# Upper and lower bound on the probability of intersection of two events.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A survey shows that $63\%$ of Americans like apples  and  $76\%$  like  cheese. If $x\%$ of Americans  like  both  cheese  and apples then

1. $x\ge 39$,
2. $x\le 63$,
3. $39\le x\le 63$,
4. None of the above.

Now since $x\%$ is a subset of the $63\%$ so $x$ must be $\le 63$.
But how do I obtain the lower bound ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $P(AB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A+B)$ and $\max(P(A),P(B))\le P(A+B)\le \min(1,P(A)+P(B))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the lower bound, let $P(A)=0.63$ and $P(C)=0.76$ (where $A$ stands for apples and $C$ for cheese). Now, by the formula of the union $$P(A\cup C)=P(A)+P(C)-P(A\cap C)\le 1$$ where the lower bound holds trivially for any probability. Hence, by rearranging $$P(A\cap C) \ge P(A)+P(C)-1=0.63+0.76-1=0.39$$

Comment: could I think of this as a derivation of Bonferroni's inequality?

Comment: @MattiaPaterna Yes, sure, but only for two events (here $A$ and $C$). For the general case of $n$ events, you should use induction and this one here as the base case. Thanks for noting.

Comment: What about the upper bound? would it be $\min(P(A), P(C))$?

Comment: @SkyWalker Yes, that is correct. The OP has it in his question, that $x<63$.